# Checked de input radio não pode ser removido

Tags: javascript, front-end, input, radiobutton

Criei 3 inputs do tipo radio, de escolha múltipla. Porém quando um input é selecionado, se clicarmos novamente, **a seleção não sai**.

```html
<fieldset class="area-interesse">
                <legend>Quais serviços da PetMais são importantes para o seu Pet?</legend>
                <div class="opcao">
                    <input type="radio" id="vet-plano-saude" class="interesse">
                    <label for="vet-plano-saude">Atendimento
                        veterinário e
                        plano de saúde PetMais.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="opcao">
                    <input type="radio" id="roupas-acessorios" class="interesse">
                    <label for="roupas-acessorios">Roupas e
                        Acessórios
                        Pet.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="opcao">
                    <input type="radio" id="alimentacao-petisco" class="interesse">
                    <label for="alimentacao-petisco">
                        Alimentação e
                        petiscos Pet.</label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

Tentei o seguinte em JS:

```js
var opcoes = document.querySelectorAll('.interesse');

for (i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++) {
    opcoes[i].onclick = function () {
        if (opcoes[i].checked)
        opcoes[i].removeAttribute('checked');
    }
}
```

Mas o console dá o seguinte **erro**:

```
main.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked')
at opcoes.<computed>.onclick (main.js:16:23)
```

Comment: Você está tentando usar o [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) como se fossem um [checkboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox). Apesar de similares esses elementos possuem semântica diferente, radio buttons são agrupados em um conjunto no qual apenas um botão de opção pode ser selecionado por vez enquanto as checkboxes permitem ativar e desativar valores únicos.

Comment: Fiz a correção. Funcionou! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até o momento não é possível desmarcar inputs do tipo radio o motivo poder ser melhor apresentado aqui nesse aqui: [Por que é impossível desmarcar botões radio](https://uxpickle.com/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-radio-buttons/#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20why%20it%27s%20impossible,default%20if%20it%20is%20required.)

Mas posso dar umas soluções:

### 1 PRIMEIRA

caso queria alternar sobre os radio use a propriedade **name** do input

```
<input type="radio" name="group" />
```

no código funcionaria como :

```html
<fieldset class="area-interesse"><legend>Quais servi&ccedil;os da PetMais s&atilde;o importantes para o seu Pet?</legend>
<div class="opcao"><input id="vet-plano-saude" class="interesse" name="group" type="radio" /> <label for="vet-plano-saude">Atendimento veterin&aacute;rio e plano de sa&uacute;de PetMais.</label></div>
<div class="opcao"><input id="roupas-acessorios" class="interesse" name="group" type="radio" /> <label for="roupas-acessorios">Roupas e Acess&oacute;rios Pet.</label></div>
<div class="opcao"><input id="alimentacao-petisco" class="interesse" name="group" type="radio" /> <label for="alimentacao-petisco"> Alimenta&ccedil;&atilde;o e petiscos Pet.</label></div>
</fieldset>
```

### 2 SEGUNDA

Usar checkbox invés de radio:
Usando JQuery

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <h3>Animals</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Tiger</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Sloth</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Cheetah</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Porque *"Tiger Sloth Cheetah"*? Para que o JQuery? Parece ter sido um exemplo copiado, porque não adaptar o exemplo do AP? É o que me impede de dar um positivo e está tendendo a um negativo caso alguém aponte  esse exemplo na internet.